# Power BI - Calculations using default and specified values in reports

Tags: powerbi

I currently have the following visual:
[MyReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsSzS.png)

I need to calculate the following things:

1) Liters of fuel used: This is simply kmsTraveled/Mileage. There is a default value of "Mileage" which is specified in an external excel file, and there are specific mileage values for some other vehicles. So if a specific mileage value is mentioned for a Vehicle_Numberplate, it should take that value for division, otherwise it should take the default value.

2) Cost of fuel consumed: The price of fuel changes every month and this monthwise table is available in another excel file. The report should have Mileage x FuelPrice to arrive at the cost. (I have a date slicer on the report page which should determine which month's rate to pick up)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. This seems to be a simple IF statement; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax

It's easier to give an exact formula if you attach a dummy setup. But the overal formula is this: 
"IF Mileage="Your name of specified milage value" THEN "kmsTraveled" / "Specific Milage Value" ELSE "kmsTraveled/Mileage""

2. If your fuel changes are based by month, then you just make a calcualted metric: "Milage x FuelPrice" and make a month filter to get the exact monthly price